# How to evenly distribute TextView on discrete seekbar ticks in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

How to evenly distribute texts above each tick mark in Discrete Seekbar?

This is how I am doing:

```
 <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/sb_task_detail_status"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:max="4"
            android:progress="0" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sb_task_detail_status"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sb_task_detail_status">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/statusRow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_newly_developed"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Newly Developed"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_developed"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Developed"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_in_progress"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="In Progress"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_completed"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Completed"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_submitted"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="5"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Submitted"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

And this is the result I got:

[image]

Note that only one TextView will be visible at a time depending on a progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `layout_width="0dp"` and assign similar weights? Like this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for each TextView

**EDIT**
I used this xml and it splits the space evenly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_task_detail_status"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:max="4"
    android:progress="0" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sb_task_detail_status"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sb_task_detail_status">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/statusRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_newly_developed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="Newly Developed"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_developed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Developed"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_in_progress"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="In Progress"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_completed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Completed"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task_status_submitted"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Submitted"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**
For anyone who wants to distribute evenly Texviews on discrete seekbar, [here's](https://www.informaticscentre.co.uk/blog/implementing-a-seekbar-with-stepped-intervals-in-android) a nice tutorial that explains all the steps to achieve it.

Comment: Sir, I have already tried this. I want to show text on top of each tick(dot) mark.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.informaticscentre.co.uk/blog/implementing-a-seekbar-with-stepped-intervals-in-android) tutorial can help you

Comment: Yup! That's great. Working like a charm. Edit your answer and paste this link in the answer and I will mark it!!!!! Thanks bro

Comment: BTW, it needs some tweaking but I will do it.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher I added the link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided didn't really space things out correctly (especially with different sized labels). They might be evenly spaced labels but that isn't quite enough to make things line up with notches on the seekbar right (last label for example would often not be positioned well).

Ideally you want the labels to be centered under the notches.

I've come up with something that uses ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider_root"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:max="3"/>

    <!-- Seek Bar notch guidlines -->
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_start_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_mid_a_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_mid_b_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_end_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/seekbar_start_guideline"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/seekbar_mid_a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/seekbar_mid_a_guideline"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/seekbar_mid_b_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/seekbar_mid_b_guideline"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fourth"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/seekbar_end_guideline"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you have more notches, you need to add guidelines spaced at the correct proportions and then set the labels to center on them (set their Left+Right constraint to equal the guideline).

Obviously the nicest solution is to then wrap this up in your own control that extends SeekBar, and dynamically builds the constaintlayout guidelines, labels and constraints based on the Max setting of seekbar.